# Can a network message be broadcasted over a UDP peer to peer connection?

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp, p2p

I have an application that is sending broadcast messages.  I have configured two computers to be connected directly between one of their network adapters.  Ping works fine between the two systems.  TCP packets are received between the systems.  I'm capturing UDP packets in Wireshark and I don't see any traffic over the port that should be receiving the broadcast messages.  Should I be able to see this traffic?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by P2P connection? It seems like you are talking about subnets in a LAN, but I am not sure...

Comment: By P2P, I mean that I'm directly connecting two machine's network adapter without using a router or hub.  Maybe I'm not using the term P2P correctly. I appologize if that is the case.

Comment: It is a type of P2P communication... (but not the only one). Such traffic can indeed be sent via broadcasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, broadcast messages can be sent between a peer to peer connection.